# Android/Java: EditText focus moves whole layout, and only ScrollView should be

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-edittext, focus

This phase is supposed to take all  basic information and add so-called "Generals", as  many as the user wants, but when I click on en "Enter your phone number" EditText, or any of the generals' EditTexts, and the virtual keyboard appears, **the whole layout gets pulled up so that the focused EditText can be visible**.

Problem is that **I need to have the top ribbon containing "Confirm" button available at all occasions**. I'm aware of the fact the user can fix that by pressing the Back button, but that'd be extremely unpractical. I need to know how to **keep the ribbon up there** after everything else gets pulled up  by the mentioned EditTexts.

Screenshot of the layout **before** mentioned EditTexts are tapped:
https://www.mediafire.com/convkey/2da9/4pa1balkda4y4d46g.jpg

Screenshot of the layout **after** mentioned EditTexts are tapped:
https://www.mediafire.com/convkey/3f9e/so8qq8vud6m3h996g.jpg

Here is layout's XML. "**topRibbonLL**" LinearLayout should always keep its place at the top, while everything else should be pulled up by tapping the mentioned EditTexts.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topRibbonLL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/firstDataTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Step 3: First data"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/confirmButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Confirm"
            android:onClick="newFileStep3ConfirmPressed" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/shareableCheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Other people can share my file" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shareableDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:text="Description of the shareableCheckBox effect."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/dataScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/dataFileName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >
            </EditText>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/dataFullName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/dataAddress"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/dataPhoneNumber"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Generals:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/generalsContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/newGeneralButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Add new general"
                    android:onClick="newGeneralButtonPressed" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Necessary EditTexts are **re-set-up** after the layout is opened, so that they'd have grey text etc.

```
private void setupNewCardEditText(final EditText editText, final String text) {
    editText.setTextColor(R.integer.tempTextColor);
    editText.setText(text);
    editText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    editText.setFocusable(true);
    editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

    editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                if (editText.getTextColors().getDefaultColor() == R.integer.tempTextColor) {
                    editText.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
                    editText.setText("");
                }
            } else {
                if (editText.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    editText.setTextColor(R.integer.tempTextColor);
                    editText.setText(text);
                }
            }
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. I used low-priority threading with a while loop to re-position the ribbon whenever it's not on top and visible. I also had to change the root layout to RelativeLayout to I could have control of the coordinates.