# EditText inside Scrollview not get focus when use request focus

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-scrollview

I have a problem when I try to use edittext.requestFocus() when the edittext inside scrollview

can any one please help

**EDIT**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/add_listitem_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/shared_list_icon_size"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/list_item_name_textview"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/shared_list_icon_size"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/larger_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/medium_margin"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:hint="@string/add_new_item"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColorHint="@color/yomi_gray_one">
</EditText>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="@dimen/shared_list_icon_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/shared_list_icon_size" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/add_list_item_imageview"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/shared_list_icon_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/shared_list_icon_size"
        android:padding="@dimen/medium_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/listitem_add_icon" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/close_list_item_imageview"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/shared_list_icon_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/shared_list_icon_size"
        android:padding="@dimen/medium_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/post_cancel" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: where is your layout file?

Comment: I don't see a `ScrollView` in your layout.

Answer (score 1):

`EditText` and `Scrollview` may have issues together. The edittext focus request will attempt to activate the soft keyboard, which impacts your scroll. So you may be getting focus, then scrolling occurs, and the scrollview regains focus... for example, the edittext begins to scroll off the screen, so it loses focus.

You may have another problem, but you will face the placement of the edittext on the screen as a problem unless you handle it, like here:

[Android/Java: EditText focus moves whole layout, and only ScrollView should be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26828374/android-java-edittext-focus-moves-whole-layout-and-only-scrollview-should-be)

or in some other way.